# How to attach MS SQL database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, mdf

I have a little problem with my mssql database.
During the creation of the database, I accidentally duplicated logical name and file names of new database. And after the deattaching of this database i'm absolutely can not attach it again, because i'm can't found .mdf file of this  database. What i'm need to do to attach this database, or it's impossible?

Picture that demonstrate what i do wrong when i try to create database
[image: Picture that demonstrate what i do wrong when i try to create database]

Picture that demonstrate files in databse folder - i can't find mdf files
[image: Picture that demonstrate files in databse folder - i can't find mdf files]

*Sorry for my english*

Comment: How could you have duplicate file name? Do you mean you have 2 files with the same name? If so, they should be in different folders.

Comment: by the way, it's better ask on DBA website: http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is shown on the first screenshot, columns "Logical name" "Files name"
I accidentally add data in column "Logical Name", and after that i lost .mdf file.

Comment: there is no duplicate on first screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think happened, I don't have enough information in your question to be sure, but what is likely is that:

1. You create the first time, SQL Server created the mdf file newDB_data.mdf
2. You detached it and SQL server removed thelogical DB but retained the newDB_data.mdf file
3. You created the second time, SQL Server tried to create newDB_data.mdf but found it was already there, so it created newDB_data2.mdf
4. You detached it and SQL server removed the logical DB but retained the newDB_data2.mdf file
5. You created the third time, SQL Server tried to create newDB_data.mdf but found it was already there, so it created newDB_data3.mdf
6. You detached the third one and SQL server removed the logical DB but retained the newDB_data3.mdf file

SO, at the end of the last detach you have the three MDF files. When you reattach, you must select the MDF file that corresponds to the LDF file. Its most likely to be be newDB_data3.mdf.

SQL Server will try to reuse the same LDF file that it had created when the detach happened.

Comment: SQL server create files without !file extensions!

Comment: Not mdf or ndf files, only files with white squares on the icons